# Python cffi fails to make a definition of value to have it detectable in the C header

Tags: python, python-cffi

I am having difficulties to wrap an existing C project into python using cffi. I managed to isolate the problem and make the minimal example. Problem is defining values. Let us consider the two following header file `s.h`

```c
#if defined(USE_HA)
#error "it was defined"
#else
#error "it was not defined"
#endif
```

and two following scenarios.

### Definitions do not work in includes from the C sources

The C source file `a.c`

```c
#include "s.h"
```

and the build script `build.py`

```py
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()

ffi.set_source(
    "mmod",
    '#define USE_HA 1',
    sources=['a.c']
)

ffi.compile()
```

now when we run `build.py` the build process crashes with `it was not defined` error.

### Definitions do work in c_header_source

Let us ignore the C source and only make the build script

```py
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()

ffi.set_source(
    "mmod",
    '#define USE_HA 1\n#include "s.h"'
)

ffi.compile()
```

when we run it, it will crash with `it was defined` indicating that the definition of `USE_HA` was recognized.

### Question

Anyone knows how to make this definition of `USE_HA` to `1` so that in the headers `defined(USE_HA)` is true not only in `c_header_source` but also in the includes from the C source files? This is exactly the problem that makes my bigger project fail to build.

Answer (score 0):

Set_source takes additional arguments to force some defines to 1 (among others). See https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffibuilder-set-source-preparing-out-of-line-modules argument "**keywords".

Answer (score 0):

It was the `define_macros` option.

```py
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()

ffi.set_source(
    'mmod',
    '',
    sources=['a.c'],
    define_macros=[('USE_HA', '1')]
)

ffi.compile()
```

this crashes with `it was defined` as expected.